# Find the Possible solution for the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

determine by inspection at least one solution of the given differential equation. That is, use your knowledge of derivatives to make an intelligent guess. Then test your hypothesis:

$xy'+ y = 3x^2$

When I tried I observed that there are product rule and power rule so I approached it backward but am stuck.
I feel like there is a concept I am unable to recall.
It would be nice to have some guidance.
Thanks in advance 
[This is what I have done after various approaches .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTPBf.jpg)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

What you did looks good:
$$xy'+ y = 3x^2$$
$$(xy)' = (x^3)'$$
You have derivatives on both sides. Integrate.
$$xy = x^3+C$$

For the solution by introspection try $y=cx^2$ as a possible solution.

Comment: I addes a line you were almost there @PriyankaJangra

Comment: Thank you so muchヾ(＾-＾)ノ     Can't believe I hve been messing up the integration

Comment: You're welcome @PriyankaJangra